# SVN Tortoiseproc.exe: show list of files or directories

Tags: svn, command-line, tortoisesvn

as the title says, is there a way to show a list of directory/files from a URL path using TortoiseProc.exe?

a sample command would be nice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use command-line, it's better and easier

But [Automating TortoiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html) anyway lists all needed for you data

```
TortoiseProc.exe /command:repobrowser /path:"URL/TO/REPO" /projectpropertiespath:"PATH/TO/WC/OF/REPO-URL" /closeonend:0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
i have another querstion, though. i just need to list it in command line and not the gui. is there a way to do it using tortoiseproc.exe?

Comment: @Roo-Gi - no (TortoiseProc is GUI-tool), just use CLI `svn ls URL > file`

Comment: Thanks @Lazy !
BTW, I just saw that svn CLI was not installed on my machine. i'll try to use CLI and implement on my script :)